# Issue on a do-while form in Strings

Tags: c, string, do-while

Ok, i'm a student in his first experiences with programmaing so be kind ;) this is the correct code to print "n" times a string on screen...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 80+1+1 /* 80+\n+\0 */

int main(void)
{
  char message[MAX];
  int i, n;

  /* input phase */
  printf("Input message: ");
  i = 0;
  do {
    scanf("%c", &message[i]);
  } while (message[i++] != '\n');
  message[i] = '\0';

  printf("Number of repetitions: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  /* output phase */
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    printf("%s", message);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

why in the do-while form he needs to check if message[i++] != '\n' and not just message[i] != '\n'??

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to write that input loop is, in my opinion, something along the lines of:

```
fgets(message, sizeof message, stdin);
```

in other words, *don't* use a character-by-character loop, just use the standard library's function that reads a string terminated by newline and be done.

Answer (score 1):

The `do { ... } while(...)` loop in your code reads characters one at a time and stores them in `message`. The index of the next character is one more that the index of the previous character, that's why we should increase index variable `i` after the current character is stored. The algorithm is:

1. Read the next character and store it in `message[i]`.
2. If this character is `'\n'`, exit.
3. Increase `i` and goto 1.

The expression `message[i++]` increments `i` after it was used as an index into `message`, so that next time we will look at the next character in the string. So, `while (message[i++] != '\n')` combines steps 2 and 3.

The same in `for`-loop:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; scanf("%c", &message[i]) && message[i] != '\n'; ++i);
```

But as @unwind pointed, it's better not to use char-by-char input.

Comment: Tnks for the answer ;) i'm not a "lover" of the do-while loop... is it possible to use a "for" loop?

Comment: what about scanf("%s", &message) ?

Comment: @JosiP: It doesn't allow to read a string that contains spaces.

Comment: hey guys can u suggest me any usefull online resource to learn C?

Comment: The best way to learn C is to read "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie. I doubt there are any online resources which are as much useful.